# How to create a progressive jpeg with html5 canvas.toDataURL

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

How to create a progressive jpeg image using canvas.toDataURL?

My code

```
canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg',0.9)
```

I found some parameters, but none of  them worked.

```
toDataURL(“image/jpeg”, {

             quality: 0..1,

             grayscale: true/false,     // since the JPEG format also     supports grayscale images at smaller files sizes

             progressive: true/false

}
```

From
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.w3c.whatwg.help/1189

Did not work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is not currently supported by the standard:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl